# Installing upgreek.sty with macports

Tags: texlive, macports

How to install `upgreek.sty` using macports? Which of texlife-* packages should I install for it?

Comment: Do you use MacTeX as your TeX distribution? If so, use the "TeX Live Utility" program -- which should have been installed at the time you downloaded and installed the MacTeX distribution -- to add packages.

Comment: I use texlive medium distribution.

Comment: This question would be better asked on a macports forum, I think. Not that it is off topic, here. Just it is more likely to get answered there. Different distributions package things differently and this is essentially a packaging issue. If you were using MacTeX, it would be different. (I recommend uninstalling the macports version and installing MacTeX but that's obviously your prerogative.)

Comment: If you have the TeXLive Package Manager, `upgreek`is part of the `was`bundle. I suppose you have to install the whole bundle.

Comment: I guess `texlive-latexextra`, as the `was` bundle belongs to `collection-latexextra` in TeX Live. I removed MacPorts from my machines long ago.

Comment: egreg, Thank you for your answer! After installing `port contents texlive-latex-extra | grep upgreek` gives:
  /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/doc/latex/was/upgreek.pdf
  /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/was/upgreek.sty

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo port install texlive-latex-extra
```

followed by, for safe measure

```
sudo texhash
```

Comment: Well, this is rather a comment than an answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, it *is* the answer (see comments to the question).

Comment: I'd also like to point out this list: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages which shows where the bundle `was` lives